# How to get proper photo (PHP) depending on screen size?

Tags: javascript, php

I have some issues with page speed depended on images that I get from server and just want to know if it is possible to get different file according to screen that page is displayed on. I found

```
if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
//Non-IE
xx = window.innerWidth;
yy = window.innerHeight;
} else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
xx = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
yy = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
} else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
//IE 4 compatible
xx = document.body.clientWidth;
yy = document.body.clientHeight;
}
```

That is possibly providing variable for later use, mainly I am focused on aspect if it is possible to get different img size througt

```
{php} $x=1; $this->assign('varX',$x); {/php} 
    {foreach from=$offer->GetPhotos() item=photo} 
    {if $varX ==1} 
        {assign var="fotourl" value=$photo->GetImgSrc('253_161', false, false, false)}
        <div class="item active">
          <a href="oferta.html?id={$offer->GetId()}">
          <img alt="Front view of the house." class="lazyload img-responsive wp-post-image" data-original="{$photo->GetImgSrc('253_161', false, false, false)}" height="161" src="{$photo->GetImgSrc('253_161', false, false, true)}" width="253"></a>
        </div>
    {else}
        <div class="item lazy-load-item">
        <a href="oferta.html?id={$offer->GetId()}">
        <img alt="Luxury Villa In Rego Park" class="img-responsive" data-lazy-load-src="{$photo->GetImgSrc('253_161', false, false, true)}"></a>
        </div>
{/if} 
{php} $x=$x+1; $this->assign('varX',$x); {/php} 
{/foreach}
```

I want to achieve moment when I can get different size of photo for desktop and mobile
Thank You in advance

Comment: You would need a way to assign the javascript variables, obtained by querying the screen dimensions, as PHP variables. A quick ajax call to set a session variable might the answer. Once you have that information available in php then yes, you should be able to deliver content suitable for the device. that is one way anyway perhaps

Comment: Start by abstracting out your PHP. It has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Then throw away that JavaScript code that tries to be backward compatible with IE4. We're some way past needing anything like that now!

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is called 'responsive design'; that is, as site where the page adapts to the size of the browser window. It's a very common requirement, and involves a lot more than just adapting the image sizes. But image size is one aspect of it.

In today's internet, you should not need to do any server-side scripting at all in order to achieve a good responsive design.

Page layout can adapt dynamically to screen size by the use `@media` blocks in your CSS. This is the most common thing people think of when talking about responsive design.

Image file sizes (the bit you're asking about) can be made responsive by use of two relatively new HTML features: `scrset` and the `picture` element.

- `scrset` is a new attribute for the existing `<img>` tag. It allows you to specify different image files for the element, and for the browser to chose the most appropriate one based on the screen size. You would use it like so:

  ```
  <img src="default-size.jpg" srcset="medium-size.jpg 1000w, large-size.jpg 2000w">
  ```

  [You can read more about `srcset` here](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/).
- The `picture` element is more complex. It does much the same thing, but allows the developer much more control over exactly which image is displayed, rather than leaving it to the browser. An example:

  ```
  <picture>
   <source srcset="smaller-image.png" media="(max-width: 800px)">
   <img src="default-image.png">
  </picture>
  ```

  In this example, you are telling the browser to use the smaller image when the page is viewed in a small browser window less than 800 pixels wide, eg maybe on a mobile device. You're being more explicit about it than the plain `srcset` example.

  [Find out more about the picture element from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture).

Note that both of these HTML features are relatively new, and thus may not be supported on older browsers. However they have been supported long enough to be in place for the majority now, and both of them have a graceful fallback of defaulting to the main image in the `<img>` tag if they aren't supported by the browser. Thus your IE9 user will just see the original base image regardless of his screen size; but it will at least work for him at that level.

So in summary, you should not need any PHP code for this, nor any JavaScript code. Just learning a few new bits of HTML.

[Edit] Regarding the browser support point I mentioned above, @FodorZoltán suggested that I link to the compatibility tables:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=picture
- http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Answer (score 0):

This can be only handled on client-side by javascript: (the second aproach is cleaner)

1. Get your different sized image paths from PHP into JS

   - var images = { 'image1ID' : {large: '{$image1largepath}', small: '{..}', ..}, 'image2ID': .. };
2. On document load get the size of the screen in JS
3. Loop the images array above, get the element by id(which is the key in the array), and update src attribute according to the screen size

Another way would be by setting attributes on your images: img-dynamic, large-src='', small-src='' etc. and runing a function in JS that would get the size of the screen, get all img elements with this img-dynamic and set their src attributes value to the large-src or small-src value according to size.

```js
var windowH = 800, windowW = 1000;

/* First get window sizes */

function setDynamicImagePaths(to){
  var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[img-dynamic]');
  for(var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++){
    imgs[i].src = imgs[i].getAttribute(to);
  }
}

/* 
 When your sure that the img elements are loaded
 ex: onload or at the end of the body
 call this
 */

window.onload = function(){
  if(windowH > 700 && windowW > 900)
    setDynamicImagePaths('src-large');
  else
    setDynamicImagePaths('src-small');
}
```

```html
<img img-dynamic width='100' height='100' src-small='noimgpath' src-large='https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2015/10/01/21/39/background-image-967820_960_720.jpg'/>
```

Comment: You would also be able to use client side javascript to send the current window size to the server, which could then generate an image of the relevant size, save that and return the image URL for javascript to then update.  There's no need to have a load of arrays in the source, or multiple sources in the image tags.

Comment: @gabe3886 Yes it is true, but that would require an additional request to the server, which would slow down things on client-side and on server-side aswell. Your aproach wouldn't be responsive (in JS you can then call this function again to update in case the browser resizes) and it's just not worth for saving that additional string output (which in fact is really insignificant due to compression).

Comment: There's really no need to use scripting here at all. Modern browsers do all of this for you using `scrset` attribute.

Comment: @Simba If you can afford to drop backward support yes, your way is the go. This srcset is actually not supported on android browsers and IE. Could you include this link in your answer as I can't comment under it :( http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset

Comment: I agree (and I will amend the answer to include the link). However the beauty of srcset and picture is that unsupported browsers will pick up the default image, so users get a working site whatever browser they're on. Pick a sensible default and you shouldn't have any issues.